# How does nikha mut'ah end, and can I immediately marry the same girl again or does she have to marry someone else first?

Tags: shiism, nikah-al-mutah

How to end my Nikha Mut'ah term? At the end of my Nikha Mut'ah term, can I directly marry the same girl again or does she have to marry someone else before marrying me?

Answer (score 1):

In contract of Nikha mut'ah you set a fixed expiration date. The nikha only ends at that expiration date, there is no divorce in nikha mut'ah. The husband may choose to forego his remaining time with the wife.

You can renew the contract with the same woman after its expiry. Without requiring the woman to marry someone else since that requirement is only for divorce and that too for three times divorced.

- https://www.al-islam.org/muta-temporary-marriage-islamic-law-sachiko-murata/statutes-muta
- http://www.alulbayt.com/rulings/11.htm
- https://www.sistani.org/english/qa/01245/

Answer (score 0):

How does Nick Mutah end and can I remarry the same girl immediately or should she marry someone else first?
There is no divorce in a temporary marriage. It ends with the end of time. Or the man says I gave the rest of the time to my wife. A man can marry a woman who is still in his temporary marriage and his period has not expired. In a temporary marriage, after the end of the mentioned period, the husband and wife can renew it or separate.

Ref: https://vakile-man.ir/4719/%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%86-%D8%B5%DB%8C%D8%BA%D9%87-%D9%85%D9%88%D9%82%D8%AA-%D9%87%D8%B1-%D8%A2%D9%86%DA%86%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF-%D8%B5%DB%8C%D8%BA%D9%87/